# Script injected by extension to gmail not connecting to DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am making a chrome extension that interacts with Gmail. The script is injected properly, but for some reason I can't interact with the DOM. First, I tried:

```
// script.js

console.log("injected successfuly.");
$('tr').hover(function() {
    console.log("hovered");
});
```

And when that didn't work, I tried something more simple:

```
console.log("injected successfuly.");
$('*').css('color', 'red');
```

Which also didn't work. The manifest is good because if it wasn't, I wouldn't see the "injected successfuly" message in the console. What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you included the call to jQuery properly? Do you need to wrap your code in `$(function () { // code });` in a docready function?

Comment: Are you even _injecting jQuery_ together with your script? Also, you might look into `all_frames` property for content scripts.

Comment: @Xan I did inject jQuery with my script. I tried setting all_frames to true, but still no success.

Comment: There are full,working examples in the docs that use jquery. See them